# Trying to run spark job written in R Language

Tags: r, apache-spark, hadoop, cloudera

I am Using cloudera destro and  trying to submit spark application writen in R langauge using 
Spark2-submit test.R

but having following issue while submitting job

```
Error: sparkr.zip does not exist for R application in YARN mode.
```

Comment: Perhaps you don't have a proper path to Windows binary R packages? Voting to close as not having sufficient code to allow meaningful further responses.

Comment: Are you sure Cloudera actually supports SparkR?